# Unexpected behaviour on model change

Tags: angularjs

Mornin', SO.

I am having some trouble with a small editable objects applet I'm working on.

I've made the snippet into a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/DUkyRmREz16n33OJrMWa?p=preview).

And I also took the time to make it into a small gif.

[image: Unexpected behaviour]

Going through with my debugger of choice (AngularJS Batarang for Chrome) I notice that the variable $scope.active doesn't update until there's an update in the actual DOM, or to a model.

Am I approaching this totally wrong by having this much logic stationed at the controller level?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? and yes your controllers should be slimmer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `ng-options` to create the repeated options:

```
<select ng-model="main.objects[active].parameter" 
        ng-options="parameter.text for parameter in main.parameters">
  <option disabled value="0">Pick one...</option>
</select>
```

This way, when one of the links is reactivated, the previously chosen option will be selected for you.

Here is an update of your plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/KuQ2SAVRTzZhmCXGxHNU?p=preview